# An identity for $q-$Fibonacci numbers if $q$ is a root of unity.

Tags: reference-request, fibonacci-numbers, q-analogs

In his proof of the Rogers-Ramanujan identities I. Schur introduced two $q-$analogues of the Fibonacci numbers ${F_n}({q})$ and ${G_n}({q})$, which satisfy

${F_0}({q})=0$,  ${F_1}({q})=1$ and  $${F_n}({q})={F_{n-1}}({q})+q^{n-2}{F_{n-2}}({q})$$ and ${G_0}({q})=0$,  ${G_1}({q})=1$ and  $${G_n}({q})={G_{n-1}}({q})+q^{n-1}{G_{n-2}}({q}).$$
Computer experiments suggest that if $k$ is not a multiple of $5$ and  ${\zeta _k }$ a primitive $k-$th root of unity then for each positive integer $n$
$${F_{kn}}({\zeta _k }) {G_{kn}}({\zeta _k })=F_{n}^2$$
holds. For example $${F_{4n}}({i}) {G_{4n}}({i})=F_{n}^2$$
The special case $${F_{k}}({\zeta _k }) {G_{k}}({\zeta _k })=1$$  for  $k \equiv  \pm 2\bmod 5$ follows from a result by L. Carlitz, Solution of Problem H- 138, Fibonacci Quart. 8(1), 1970, 76-81.

Is there a proof in the literature for  the general identity or at least for $n=1$ and  $k \equiv  \pm 1\bmod 5$?